# Word for a system that exhales gas

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

I'm looking for a word to describe a system that filters certain gases from a space and 'exhales' them outside. What verb can be used to describe that action?

Comment: Like a [hot gas filtration system?](http://www.google.com/#q=hot+gas+filtration+system&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=imvns&ei=v2WlT6zvFcrG6AGb-ZjSBA&start=0&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=6b4b1bdf32659c2&biw=1366&bih=552) What kind of gases? In medicine, there are anesthetic gas scavenging systems. Can you provide a little more context?

Comment: As JLG says, without more specifications it is difficult to answer to this question.

Answer (score 7):

I think you are looking for the word *[exhaust](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exhaust?region=us&q=exhaust)*.

> expel (gas or steam) from or into a particular place.

*[Exhaust systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exhaust_system)* are typically part of car engines, but can also be found on stoves or other gas-producing systems.